# display photos from facebook page on my website using php

Tags: php, facebook, api, photos, facebook-graph-api

I have a client who has asked me to display all of the photos from his facebook page to his website. I chose to use PHP, but I can also go with Javascript if that makes more sense. I created a little PHP script that found his page's access token based off my access token (as an admin). The PHP script searched through all of the albums on his facebook page and displayed them correctly. I was very excited and thought I had it figured out but then come to find out my access token expires, so when I visited the webpage that was supposed to show up a bunch of photos showed me a blank screen.

I have looked online and it looks like once you get an app id and app secret, you can get an access token pretty easily. I have created an app now, but I cannot figure out how to tie (merge) the facebook app with the client's facebook page. Any ideas? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and set up a link within an iFrame such as this:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

As a basic idea of what you can use.  If you're building an app to do this, you would need to provide an example for review.

Comment: Well, the client already has a facebook page. Is there a way to just use a facebook app id to get the access token for that particular facebook page? Can I merge a facebook page with a facebook app?

Comment: this will help you http://rieglerova.net/how-to-get-a-facebook-app-id/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/